# Buttons behind view are active

Tags: objective-c, view, uipickerview

In xcode I have a secondary view that appears on top of my main view upon a click of a button. The problem that I am having is that although this secondary view appears on top of my main view, when I use  my UIPickerView in the secondary view, buttons in the main view are still active and get clicked on when I am using the picker in the secondary view. Is there a property on the picker or the secondary view that I can active so they are set as topmost and do not let buttons behind them work?

Answer (score 0):

Every view inheriting from UIView has the "userInteractionEnabled" property (more details in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled)

You should set this property to YES in your view/picker. In interface builder, there is a checkbox to check in the Attributes inspector under View > Interactions > User Interaction Enabled.

Hope that helps.